# password protection for logrotate compression

Tags: linux, password, compression, gzip, logrotate

Is password protection possible with `logrotate` while compressing in Linux? If yes would someone let me know how?

```
/root/NewLog {
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    size 20k
    daily
    create 0600 root root
}
```

So I limit the file size and compress it with compress attribute. How about password protecting it?

Comment: use `postrotate` option and call a script which does password protection.

Comment: use zip -PPASSWORD in postrotate section